# No module named werkzeug.local

Tags: python, module, local, release, werkzeug

I'm trying to run odoo server by using the following command (~/opt/odoo8.0/odoo-server$ ./odoo.py --addons-path=/opt/odoo8.0/odoo-server, opt/odoo8.0/odoo)

But i'm getting the following error (from werkzeug.local import Local, release_local
ImportError: No module named werkzeug.local) ho wcan i fix it ?

Comment: I went to the repo and copy-pasted the file to my local copy.  Crude, but it werked.

Answer (score 0):

This means, the required module 'werkzeug' is not installed in your Python environment. you can install it using this command `pip install werkzeug` .

If you still have an error make sure you are using the right environment (with all the requirements installed) to run the command.